# React Component iterate/loop properties of Mongo object

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, mongodb-query

I do have a Mongo `collection` that stores albums with predefined "slot" for its images and feel a bit stuck if there a way to loop over the properties of the collection in order to display images in separated divs.

I did used this code for mapping over the album covers and it worked great:

```
albums() {
  return Albums.find().fetch();
}

{this.albums().map( (album) => {
  return <div key={album._id}><img src={album.cover} /></div>
 })}
```

But now I ask you to help, is it possible to loop over photoOne, photoTwo, etc... and skip/don't display data if it is empty like in photoThree for example.

```
{
    "_id" : "CHMHbNWWwZGaLGvB6",
    "title" : "Text",
    "cover" : "link",
    "createdAt" : date,
    "photoOne" : {
        "titleOne" : "Text",
        "coverOne" : "link"
    }
    "photoTwo" : {
        "titleTwo" : "Text",
        "coverTwo" : "link"
    }
    "photoThree" : {
        "titleThree" : "",
        "coverThree" : ""
    }
}
```

Comment: can you change the data structure at all? it would be more standard and easier to work with to have a collection for photos, which is an array with objects inside

Comment: @AndrewAxton I am pretty new to all of this, can you please point me to some sources in which way I could refacture the code?

Comment: @AdrianSoleil You can look into embedded documents here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Comment: @CodyParker thank you a lot for this link, the idea looks great, but I do still feel confused about how to map over the property of mongo collection.

Comment: @AdrianSoleil - The answer I gave below should do what you were wanting in your initial question. The link I provided is just more information on what Andrew and I mentioned, which is to structure the data in a way that makes iterating the photos much less of a pain. Did my answer below not work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Mongo user, but in the map function you can check for the existing values, and handle it there. Something like (there is surely a cleaner way, though):

```
   this.albums().map( (album) => {
       for (key in album){
         if (key.startsWith('photo')){
           var title = Object.keys(album[key])[0];
           if (album[key][title].length != 0){
             console.log("Can use: " + Object.keys(album[key])[0])
           }
         }
       }
   })
```

Results in:

```
Can Use This: titleOne
Can Use This: titleTwo
```

Hope that helps, but it seems like having the photos with photoOne, photoTwo you are limiting the number of photos to use and requiring the need to use Object.keys to get the values out (without specifically using album.photoOne, album.photoTwo, etc.

If the album photos were stored in an embedded document, you could just include the photos and titles that existed and avoid having to check for empty ones. You would just loop through the photos that are present....if that makes sense.

Comment: Hello, Cody. I've just came back to this problem. I do appreciate a lot for your help, what you have proposed looks great, I did walked through mdn documentation, but have encountered the following issue: when I console.log((Object.keys(album)[0].startsWith('photo')) it gives false. When I console.log(album) it gives this: Object {_id: "4kBBPjrA5CXxJSJLR", title: "Super", cover: "link", createdAt: date, photoOne: Object…} indexOf returns -1 for any character from the key

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood how this.Albums() was...assuming albums  is an array of dictionaries, like the dict you show above, the newly updated code in my answer should work.